# how to connect java library to project to test the library

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

So I need to connect a library to my repo in IntelliJ, so I can test the library as it interacts with my main project. And I got this command from a member on my team: "So you need to change .java files in entity manager (which is the library) repo and do mvn clean package to generate the jar file locally, the use that jar in your project repo.
Then create dummy folder in your project with the same package name and copy those .java files from entity manager."

What does change the java files mean? What about "use that jar"? I'm so confused.

Comment: It sounds like you need to use a .jar file generated by another project into yours right?

Comment: If the above is correct, can you also confirm if your project also uses maven( does it have pom.xml at the root?)

Comment: @gtiwari333 Yea I guess so, so I currently have moved the other project's java files into a folder in my own projects, but they're red in IntelliJ which I'm guessing means they aren't really connected.

Comment: yea it has a pom.xml

Comment: ok. what do you mean by `to test the library`? are you going to write unit tests for that project? Are you using that jar file for some other purpose?

Comment: no so there's a bug in the library, and I need to edit and debug the files

Comment: If there's a bug in that library then you might want to checkout that project and write unit test OR run tests/app. You might not need to copy anything.

Answer (score 1):

If you do `mvn clean package` it produces a .jar file in target/ folder. Use that dependency to your project if they both share a common parent pom.xml

If you do `mvn clean install` it produces the jar file in target/ folder + copies the .jar file to your local m2 folder. That way you can use that .jar file to any project locally. Just use the  with matching version, artifact and groupId whereever you need to use that jar file.

For both options above, you need to define sth like below in your pom.xml

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.my.library</groupId>
        <artifactId>mylib-artifact</artifactId>
        <version>1.VERSION</version>
</dependency>
```

Not recommended:

- You can also put the .jar file to your project (without doing `mvn clean install`) See: http://blog.gtiwari333.com/2016/12/maven-use-local-jar-without-installing.html
- Or manually add the .jar to your project as project dependency using your IDE's project configuration

Answer (score 0):

Use "mvn install" instead of package. This puts the library into your local .m2 repo and makes it available to your project in idea